# Oracle Apex - Branch to another page on change of radio button

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to implement following:

I have a radio group defined on the Landing page of my application. It contains 6 different options. I have another page which contains a form with some items to be filled by the user.
Whenever the user chooses a particular option of the radio group on the landing page, it should branch to the other page with 1 specific item enabled among other items.
If the user chooses any other option of the radio group, it should branch to the other page with that specific item disabled.
I can implement the whole thing on a single page but failing in case of two pages!

Comment: How to branch when the value of radio option changes. and then how to disable/enable specific item.

Comment: Can you detail the "settings" of your radio group? They can be set to submit on change - would this be suitable?